# Problem assigning data to tableview - Swift

Tags: swift

Although I load the data into the gifsa string array in the function, I cannot see the gifsa data in the tableView. gifsa data does not appear in tableView. The data is loading data in the veriCek() function. However, it does not load data into the imageView found in cell. What is the problem?

```
class NewDegisimController: UITableViewController {

    var gifsa: [String] = []
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return gifsa.count
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
        veriCek()
    }
 func veriCek(){
        let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
                  client.connect("...", username: "...", password: "...", database: "...") { success in
                  client.execute("SELECT ... FROM ...", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
                   for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                    for row in table {
                    for (_, value) in row {
                      if let intVal = value as? String {
                        self.gifsa.append(String(intVal))
                      }} }}
                      client.disconnect()
                  }) }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        let model = models[indexPath.row]

    do {
        print("gifsaas",self.gifsa)

                         let url = URL(string: self.gifsa[indexPath.row])
                           let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
                            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
                           cell.textLabel?.text = model.title
                           }
                           catch{
                               print(error)
                           }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: `client.execute` is an async call. You have to add `self.tabelView.reloadData()` in the completion handler after loading the data.

Comment: I didn't think of it, thank you :) @RickyMo

Comment: Unrelated but you are strongly discouraged from loading image data synchronously and uncached in `cellForRow`. Don't do that. It will cause very bad user experience. And why do you create a string from a string with `String(intVal)`? The variable name is pretty misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call

```
self.tableView.reload()
```

in your `veriCek()` function and you are all set

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload

```
               for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                for row in table {
                for (_, value) in row {
                  if let intVal = value as? String {
                    self.gifsa.append(String(intVal))
                  }} }}
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
```